# Spark create dataframe with a column mixed of integer and float numers

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create an spark data frame with a column of numbers, which some of them are integer and others are float:

```
tmp = spark.createDataFrame([1.0, 2.1, 3], IntegerType()).toDF('bins')
```

It raises this error:

> TypeError: field value: IntegerType can not accept object 1.0 in type <class 'float'>

how can I create a data frame with `1.0, 2.1, 3` in a column? It should be `3` and can't be cast to float like: `3.0`. also `2.1` can't be cast to `2`.
if I use this command instead:

```
tmp = spark.createDataFrame([1.0, 2.1, 3], FloatType()).toDF('bins')
```

It raises this error:

> TypeError: field value: FloatType can not accept object 3 in type <class 'int'>

how can I creat this data frame?

Comment: You cannot do that. Even if you could, you should not. Why cannot you have a `3.0` ?

Comment: actually I can have ````3.0```` but what if this list became an auto-generated list of numbers? should I cast all integers to float? @BlueSheepToken

Comment: I think so, they are supposed to mathematically represent the same thing. You got sometimes precision error on floats, but this is all you can do if you have mixed numeric types

Comment: alright
so that's the answer. thanks @BlueSheepToken

Comment: With pleasure !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here could be your solution :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W, types as T

tmp = spark.createDataFrame(map(float, [1.0, 2.1, 3]), T.FloatType()).toDF("bins")
```

or another one :

```py
tmp = (
    spark.createDataFrame([1.0, 2.1, 3], T.StringType())
    .toDF("bins")
    .withColumn("bins", F.col("bins").cast(T.FloatType()))
)
```